# Don't allow access to example.com/image/pic.jpg using htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache2

I have two domains for the same website.
example.com and example2.com .

I don't want the `/image/pic.jpg` to be accessible for the example.com
It means, if someone try to visit `example.com/image/pic.jpg` , it will show him/her error. But I want it to be accessible for example2.com visitors. So if someone visit `example2.com/image/pic.jpg` , they will be able to to see the picture

How can I do that using htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using mod_rewrite at the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^image/pic\.jpg$ - [F]
```

The preceding *condition* checks the requested host (`example.com` or `www.example.com` in this example).

This returns a 403 Forbidden if `example.com/image/pic.jpg` is requested. Otherwise, it doesn't do anything.